# Firestore get subcollection from where query

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a structure like this:

```
user/user_id/books/book_id
```

I'd like to get the collection of books of a user that have a specific phone. So I'd use:

```
firestore.collection('user').where('phone', '==', specificPhone)
```

But after that, how do I get the books subcollection? Do I have to manually do another query?

I only want to get the first coincidence, since `where` returns a set of results. Also I want to retrieve the data only once, not listen to changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore reads are shallow; they don't read data from subcollections. So you'll indeed need to perform another read operation to get the books for the users that you found in your first query.

For example:

```
let user = await firestore.collection('user').where('phone', '==', specificPhone).get();
let books = await user.ref.collection("books").get();
books.forEach((bookDoc) => {
  console.log(book.id, book.data());
});
```

Comment: I thought there would be another way to go, but this is also very concise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could get multiple results from the collection query, so you should map the results and get the subcollection

Try something like this using the switchMap operator from rxjs

```
   firestore.collection.where('phone', '==', specificPhone).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
        .pipe(
          switchMap((users) => {
            const us = users.map((user) => {
              return firestore
                .collection(`users/${user.id}/books`, ref => ref.orderBy('sortOrder'))
                .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
                .pipe(
                  map(books => Object.assign(user, {books}))
                );
              });
            return combineLatest([...us]);
          })
```

Comment: I would like to have only the first result in that case, and also I don't want to listen to changes; I want only to read the values once. I'll update my question. Thanks!